# WhatsApp issue on Android

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

We have a WhatsApp number dedicated to providing training to students all over the world. We have 13191 contacts saved in phone and there are 19103 chats in WhatsApp. We also have 50 broadcast list. We are facing the following issues in WhatsApp,

1. When we set status in WhatsApp, it gets hanged. We need to force stop the app and then restart to use it again. It keeps happening when setting Whatsapp status.
2. When we reply to any chat message, it takes around 5 mins to get reached.
3. When sending any message in a broadcast list, it takes around 10 mins to reach the contacts.

We are using an Android Samsung tablet with a storage of 64GB and 4GB of RAM.

What to do to resolve the above issues?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using web.whatsapp.com ? I find that using this method helps sometimes. Maybe also consider deleting the app's cache, and reinstalling the app from the google play store. Sometimes the app's cache gets fragmented.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using regular WhatsApp, try to use WhatsApp for business app, as it's mainly designed for businesses, hope it will be more stable for more number of chats.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer may be not in android, but in the web service, you should maybe use [this](https://web.whatsapp.com/). There are some limmitations but you should try. In my actual phone, a Galaxy S5, Whatsapp freezes when I receive several notifications in a short time.